# Deadlock when unit testing with Algolia Android client

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, junit, algolia

I am trying to use `searchAsync` from algolia in a JUnit test, but it ends in a deadlock as the search results are not coming back. Here is my code:

```
    final Index index = AlgoClient.initIndex("contacts");

    Query query = new Query();

    query.setHitsPerPage(100);

    CountDownLatch signal = new CountDownLatch(1);

    index.searchAsync(query, new CompletionHandler() {

        @Override
        public void requestCompleted(JSONObject content, AlgoliaException e) {

           signal.countDown();
        });

    signal.await();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use await with a timeout, and fail if it does timeout. Also, you should test for an error in your `CompletionHandler`:

```
final Index index = client.getIndex("contacts");
    Query query = new Query().setHitsPerPage(100);
    final CountDownLatch signal = new CountDownLatch(1);

    index.searchAsync(query, new CompletionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void requestCompleted(JSONObject content, AlgoliaException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                signal.countDown(); // Request success
            } else { 
                fail(e.getMessage()); // Request error
            }
        }
    });

    try {
        if (!signal.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) { // returns false when timeout
            fail("Didn't count down");
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        fail("interrupted");
    }
```